# How to style a custom element directly from CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, html

HTML5 Rocks has a [great article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) on creating custom elements, there is also [an article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/#toc-style-host) on styling them.

To register a custom element I can do:

```
var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo', {
  prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype)
});
```

I now can use `x-foo` in my body.

```
<body>
    <x-foo>Hello</x-foo>
</body>
```

Now my question is: how to style a `<x-foo />` element (in the body) from CSS? I would like to keep my HTML clean, so I don't want to append any classes or ids.

The article made me assume it should be:

```
:host(x-foo) { 
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: style it as tag, or assign an `#id-name` or a `.class-name` to target it from CSS  https://jsfiddle.net/s7v3pajz/1/

Comment: You use :host when styling from within the shadow dom, when styling from parent page you just use normal selector

Answer (score 0):

You should really use ID's and classes in HTML, it doesn't make your code messy at all. But this should do what you are asking for.

```
body x-foo{
  color: red;
}
```

I would recommend to add an id or class to the `<x-foo>` tag like so `<x-foo id="myID"></x-foo>`

```
#myID{
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit more.
`<x-foo>Bar</x-foo>` is cleaner than `<div class="foo-bar"></div>` IMHO

Comment: Defining custom elements is the new way to do it. Using unmeaningful `<div>`s with a lot unnecessary classes are now considered "bad" for some people, at least to Google it is.

Comment: _“`<x-foo>Bar</x-foo>` is cleaner than `<div class="foo-bar"></div>` IMHO”_ – both are elements that have no inherent structural/sematic meaning – so I really don’t see that much of a difference here …

Answer (score 0):

After read the article I found this :

CSS

```
<style> 
  app-panel { 
    display : flex ; 
  } 
  [ is = "x-item" ]  { 
    transition : opacity 400ms ease-in-out ; 
    opacity :  0.3 ; 
    flex :  1 ; 
    text-align : center ; 
    border-radius :  50% ; 
  } 
  [ is = "x-item" ]: hover { 
    opacity :  1.0 ; 
    background :  rgb ( 255 ,  0 ,  255 ); 
    color : white ; 
  } 
  app-panel >  [ is = "x-item" ]  { 
    padding :  5px ; 
    list-style : none ; 
    margin :  0  7px ; 
  } 
</style>
```

HTML

```
    <app-panel> 
      <li  is = "x-item"> Do </ li> 
      <li  is = "x-item"> Re </ li> 
      <li  is = "x-item"> Mi </ li> 
    </ app-panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In your body(html code) you can add an **id** or **class**, whether it's not important costume  element or default element .
2. You can use tag names (here : x-foo) in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily like other basic css, for example

```
<style>
  x-foo{
    font-size:45px;
    .........
  }
</style>
```